# Error (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found

Tags: ios, flutter, mobile

Spent an hour trying to debug this error with stack overflow and GitHub. Any help appreciated. I tried the deleting iOS file and doing flutter clean and stuff.

```
Error (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
/Users/ME/Desktop/fitnessapp/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h:9:8


Error (Xcode): failed to emit precompiled header
'/Users/ME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gzhzlsjpfyzcnebymqrpzjndrlbm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/Runner-Bridging-Header-swift
_10LJ9PKPTMFQI-clang_1OUD1W5Q54EHI.pch' for bridging header'/Users/ME/Desktop/fitnessapp/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h'


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13 Pro.
```

Comment: have you got the fix?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could try to do this:

1. Backup Runner folder
2. Delete the ios folder
3. Go to a terminal and execute `flutter create .` in the flutter project folder
4. Paste your Runner folder back into the ios folder
5. `pod deintegrate` in the ios folder
6. `pod install` also in the ios folder
7. `flutter clean` in the flutter project folder
8. `flutter pub get`
9. flutter run

Please note that if you use firebase you need to re-insert the GoogleService-Info.plist file

Hope it helps, but if it still does not make sure you are in stable channel

Comment: This worked! I saw this answer in many different stackoverlfow pages and tried it like a million times. The thing I did different was to switch to the stable channel this time. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: works fine but i think i lost my notification settings

Comment: To be more precise, GoogleService-Info.plist file needs to be re-added to the files in Xcode.

Answer (score 16):

After trying Edin's solution it still didn't work for me!

Make sure that **for install builds only** box is unchecked

[for install builds only is unchecked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEbnN.png)

Comment: works as well! I tried lots of things, but I wasted my time with them, but for my problem this was the solution, thx

Comment: I had the same problem, This workaround has fixed it. Thanks

Comment: This work for me. Thanks @Kirill.

Answer (score 0):

Running `pod install` in the `ios` folder worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed the same problem like this by **removing** the
**SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER = "Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h" in buildSettings of Extension**

https://github.com/AngeloAvv/flutter_flavorizr/issues/197