# Lexical or Preprocessor Issue Xcode 15: Flutter/Flutter.h file not found

Tags: flutter, xcode

I update my flutter app to Xcode 15 and after that I get the following error after apply flutter run command.

> Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

> Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found

> /Users/pedrocovarrubias/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/vibration-1.8.2/ios/Classes/VibrationPlugin.h:0:8

> Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Could not build Objective-C module 'vibration'

So far, I had tried the following:

1. Backup Runner folder
2. Delete the ios folder
3. Go to a terminal and execute flutter create . in the flutter project folder
4. Paste your Runner folder back into the ios folder
5. pod deintegrate in the ios folder
6. pod install also in the ios folder
7. flutter clean in the flutter project folder
8. flutter pub get
9. flutter run

I had also:

- re-insert the GoogleService-Info.plist file in Xcode

I try everything that the answers of these question indicates:

[Error (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71094048/error-xcode-flutter-flutter-h-file-not-found)

[error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found when flutter run on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64973346/error-flutter-flutter-h-file-not-found-when-flutter-run-on-ios/64993852#64993852)

Additional information:

I get this after I do pod install in ios folder:

[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Runner` to `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` or include the `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Flutter/Release.xcconfig`).

[!] The `Runner [Debug]` target overrides the `ENABLE_BITCODE` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation - Use the` $(inherited)` flag, or
- Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `Runner [Release]` target overrides the `ENABLE_BITCODE` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation - Use the` $(inherited)` flag, or
- Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `Runner [Profile]` target overrides the `ENABLE_BITCODE` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation - Use the` $(inherited)` flag, or
- Remove the build settings from the target.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that error is due to your XCode update.

Please try the following solutions:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77275218/6890699